# Parent to Child communication not working as expected

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have two components, a parent and a child.
Every time I click on a certain button in the parent component, an object gets populated and sent to the child component via an `@Input` decorator.

The issue here is that even though the changes to the object are detected in the child component, the data that I'm trying to populate will only appear on even clicks.

This is what my code currently looks like:

**parent.component.ts**

```
private toSend = {};

public sendToChild() {
  var objectToSend = {
    headerMessage:`Title`, 
    bodyMessage:"Body"
  };
  this.toSend = { ...objectToSend };
  $('#childComponent').appendTo("body").modal('toggle');
}
```

**parent.component.html**

```
<child-component #childComponent [data]="toSend">
</child-component>
```

**child.component.ts**

```
public headerMessage: string = "";
public bodyMessage: string = "";

@Input('data')
set data(data: any) {
  if (data !== undefined && data.length !== 0) {
    this.setData(data);
  }
}

private setData(el): void {
  for (let key in el) {
    switch (key) {
      case "headerMessage":
        this.headerMessage = el[key];
        break;
      case "bodyMessage":
        this.bodyMessage = el[key];
        break;
    }
  }
}
```

**child.component.html**

```
<div class="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" id="childComponent">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered modal-dialog-scrollable" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header" style="padding: 1rem;">
        <h5 class="modal-title">{{headerMessage}}</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" id="btn-close-id" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body" id="modal-body-id">
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <div class="col-12">
            {{bodyMessage}}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer" style="padding: 1rem;">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I also tried with `ngOnChanges` and I was able to print the object I was sending every time but I had the same problem.

Comment: can you create a stackblitz creating this situation?

Comment: I also see jQuery syntax. Get rid of jQuery, it will mess with your DOM elements and cause unforseen problems.

Comment: Your component has a 'ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush' ?

Comment: I already tried with ChangeDetectorRef but the problems persists... I'll try with a modal of my own to see if that's what causing the issue. Could anyone reference an article that explains the problems with using jQuery with Angular? I'm kind of new to all this... Thanks!

Comment: I was able to fix the issue using BehaviorSubject to pass data between the two... I tried with this modal: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_modals.asp but I was still not being successful, so jQuery doesn't seem to be the problem here.

Answer (score 2):

You could force the detection by using the `ChangeDetectorRef`

```
import { ..., ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';
```

Add it on your constructor

```
constructor(private _cdr: ChangeDetectorRef) {...}
```

And in your child component

```
this._cdr.markForCheck();
// or if not working
this._cdr.detectChanges()
```

Another thing, JQuery is not recommanded with Angular. If you want to use modal in your project, you should check [Angular material modal](https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/overview) or make your own modal component.

Comment: I tried after the for loop is completed in the child component but it's still not working... I'm going to try to replace the bootstrap modal with one of my own and see what happens

Comment: Angular material is from the angular team, you should really try it or at least check the source code.